# Possible to order by RowKey in Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I'm trying to build a pretty simple RSS aggregator using Azure Table Storage, Azure Website and Azure WebJobs.

Lets say my table storage looks like this,

**PartitionKey** **RowKey**
A ----------------- 1
A ----------------- 5
A ----------------- 6
B ----------------- 2
B ----------------- 4
B ----------------- 7

I'm using this method, http://blog.liamcavanagh.com/2011/11/how-to-sort-azure-table-store-results-chronologically/ to set RowKeys.

And the PartitionKey is an unique identifier of each feed.

Now, if I would like to have the three newest items (A1, B2 and B3). Is it possible to do a query on two PartiotionKeys and then order by the RowKey?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you got 3 new feed items (1 in A, and 2 in B) and what you want to do is query table to get just these new feeds. Am I correct?

Comment: My question is, is it possible to do a query that only sorts on RowKey and ignoring the PartitionKey?

Comment: I don't think so. By default a query result is sorted by PartitionKey first and then RowKey for a PartitionKey even if you don't include PartitionKey in your query. Would it be an acceptable solution if you denormalize your data and store multiple copies of same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the RowKey in reverse. Instead of 1, 5, 6, etc... start with an impossibly high value (maxint) and then subtract from it. For your case, to keep from having to juggle an arbitrary ID value, perhaps instead use datatime "ticks" as the seed value.

Here's a fairly old example I did of accomplishing something that seems similar to what you're after: http://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/kicking-off-a-year-of-azureweek-1/

Comment: I don't think that this really answer my question. I'm already doing that, sort of. My question is, is it possible to sort only on RowKey and ignoring the PartitionKey?

Comment: no, PK+RK is the only index you're going to get from the table. If what you're trying to accomplish is a chronological listing of items across feeds, then might I recommend using a PK+RK combo that's entirely based on date/time? Then you can filter in memory if needed. Unless this is a highly volatile result set, the approach should work fine (especially if you cache the results). If that doesn't work, there are several patterns, based on redundant storage approaches that should work well.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it highlighted that my question couldn't easily be done the way I was hoping for.

Comment: "Clever" hacks like creating a custom descending order row key work well when YOUR data access layer is the only one in existence, but be aware that production support and bulk ETL might not be happy with that approach as it requires the exact same logic to always be applied.  Don't Repeat Yourself!